# Plot horizontal graph in Java console application

Tags: java, graph, console-application

I'm trying to make a graph to show the weight with the corresponding dates, from two ArrayLists. One with LocalDates (date of entering weight) and the other one Doubles (weight). The X axis will be the weight and the Y axis will be the date.

I have tried with some for loops, but that did not do what I wanted: I want to stay in the console and I want it to be horizontal. I don't have much code to show, only to give a little visual on what I like to achieve. I don't know if it is even possible to get what I want in a console application.

I have found some code to plot a graph vertically but I do not like the way that looks.

(In the code below I used an already filled Array, just for the visual.)

```
public void writeGraph() {
    Arrays.sort(weightSorted);

    for (int i = weightSorted.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(weightSorted[i] + "\n");
    }

    System.out.println("KG");

    System.out.print("             ");
    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.print("Date >       ");
    for (int in = 0; in < weighDate.length; in++) {
        System.out.print(weighDate[in] + "    ");
    }
}
```

That will look like this:

```
90.0

86.0

83.8

83.3

81.0

78.5

75.0

73.9

70.3

65.5

KG
              
Date >       2021-01-14    2021-02-25    2021-03-06    2021-04-04    2021-05-11    2021-06-20    2021-07-02    2021-08-28    2021-09-15    2021-10-07
```

And then I want the weights on the y axis doubled above the corresponding dates on the x axis.. I hope this can get you an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is try to plan the output graph structure in a character grid. Count how many characters every part of your graph has, then plan the spaces around them.

Also, I think maybe a `Map<LocalDate, Double>` will give you better tools to handle the data.

After that, consider maybe creating a method that using the X/Y data you have, builds the corresponding horizontal line. i.e: For 81KG line, see if there is a X/Y data point with that value in any date, then, if so, plot it in the appropriate character (vertical line) in the string.

TLDR: Build one line at a time, from top to bottom, using the data you have and planning the spaces you need.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I will have a look at that.